# How to get childs hwnd of game?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I want to send some message to textinput label to client of some game but i can't find hwnd. I use this code :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lp);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    while( !( hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "GameClient") ) )
    {
        Sleep(500);
        std::cout << "Waiting for launch...\n";
    }
    EnumChildWindows(hWnd, &EnumChildProc, NULL);

    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lp)
{
    char buff[128];
    GetClassName(hWnd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    std::cout << buff <<"\n";
    return true;
}
```

This just find main window where the title is located and nothing more, like this is not main hwnd and havn't childs, but i checked with WinSpy and also can't find any windows because always get only hwnd with window tittle. This code works good with AkelPad and other but not with client of a game. I guess it's something special with this in games like directx or something else. So what i can do?

Comment: If the game's text input is windowless, there's nothing you can do unless the game explicitly helps you do so (e.g. it supports the accessibility API, or exposes an OLE Automation interface, etc.).

Comment: It's worth a shot sending `WM_CHAR/WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP/...` messages to the main window of the game. That way you're "simulating" keyboard usage and with a little luck the game processes it...

Comment: @LukasThomsen: See these: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) and [Simulating input via WM_CHAR messages may fake out the recipient but it won't fake out the input system](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/28/10190521.aspx).